# Fixtures for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing, fixture

Are there any Python tools to create fixtures on Google App Engine? I tried Fixture(http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture/). It is the most awesome tool I have come across. I love the clean approach and the consistency of the APIs. But it is LGPL licensed. Our project is licensed under Apache License 2.0 and AFAIK LGPL is incompatible with this license. Can some one please suggest any other tool similar to Fixture but with Apache compatible license?

Comment: LGPL isn't incompatible with Apache; in fact, the FSF specifically recommends people not license with the LGPL because it allows people to use the code in non-GPL projects.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the fixtures just for testing your app?  If so, I don't think the license of your app matters at all.  It would only be important if you were redistributing the fixtures functionality.